# Using while to receive data from column in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm attempting to iterate across multiple columns in 1 row and use the information in each column to run a command against. (i.e. A1 = CO, B1 = NO, C1 = NO2) The table that contains this is c_locations_of_interest.

The command I have written is

```
While c_locations_of_interest(1,i) ~= ''
   statements
   i = i + 1
end
```

This errors out though. How can I set it so it will run the statement against each of the inputs for A1, then B1, then C1 until it reaches an empty column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the column indexes and `break` if the value satifies the test:

```matlab
for c = 1:width(c_locations_of_interest)
    if (c_locations_of_interest{1,c} == '')
        break
    end
    disp(c) % do stuff
end
```

Also you should verify that your empty values are actually `''`. For example if they're `nan`, you should test for `isnan()` instead:

```matlab
    if (isnan(c_locations_of_interest{1,c}))
```